# Получить запись из бд, у которой одно из "полей" является массивом

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, yii2, yii

В бд присутствует  вот такая вот связка таблиц, т.е у одного продукта может быть множество тегов, и один тег может встречаться у множества продуктов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из бд для вывода на страницу 1 продукта, мне нужно вывести имя,цену, а также список всех привязанных к этому продукту тегов.

Делаю все это на yii2.
На текущий момент задача решается такой вот конструкцией из запросов с циклом. Можно ли получить тот же набор данных, но одним запросом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Можно ли получить тот же набор данных, но одним запросом?* Сперва реализуйте на чистом SQL, а потом смотрите, как это перенести на уй. [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035)

Comment: и почему вы не используете ORM, который предоставляет yii2 ? там есть модели и отношения

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/db-active-record#junction-table напишите потом нечто вроде `Product::find()->with(['Tag'])->all()` и все